# Authorize.Net CIM: How to send createProfile=true into the transaction with PHP API

Tags: php, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

The API docs say to set createProfile to true. I can't find an example of this so after searching around I found the setCreateProfile method. I'm using it like this. I get no errors.

$this->custpaymentprofile = new AnetAPI\CustomerProfilePaymentType();
$this->custpaymentprofile->setCreateProfile(true);

What I can't figure out is how to send this setting through the transaction so that a customer profile gets created.

All the other data is sent through AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType()

IE: $this->transactionRequestType->setOrder($this->order);

Everything else works, I can run a successful transaction, just need to get it to create a profile.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
$profile = new AnetAPI\CustomerProfilePaymentType();
$profile->setCreateProfile(true); 
$transactionRequestType->setProfile($profile);
```